# How to validate an integer range is not included in another integer range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to create a validation for a period, so one period does not contain another period inside it.

i.e period one is from 25-30 and if period two is created to be 20-40 it should error

I was trying to validate it by using

```
def period_cannot_inbetween_and_other_period
    return unless period_overlap(start_week, finish_week).any?
    errors.add(:start_week, '-', :finish_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
  end
```

and

```
def period_overlap(start_week, finish_week)
    self.class.where(':start_week <= start_week AND :finish_week >= finish_week', start_week, finish_week)
  end
```

entire code is below

```
class Period < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :days_till_sellables, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :organization
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :start_week, presence: true
  validates :finish_week, presence: true
  validates :start_week, inclusion: { in: (1..52), message: '%<value>s must be a valid week number' }
  validates :finish_week, inclusion: { in: (1..52), message: '%<value>s must be a valid week number' }

  validate :start_week_cannot_overlap_period
  validate :finish_week_cannot_overlap_period
  validate :start_week_cannot_overlap_period_wrap_around
  validate :finish_week_cannot_overlap_period_wrap_around
  validate :period_cannot_inbetween_and_other_period

  protected

  def start_week_cannot_overlap_period
    return unless regular_overlap(start_week).any?
    errors.add(:start_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
  end

  def finish_week_cannot_overlap_period
    return unless regular_overlap(finish_week).any?
    errors.add(:finish_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
  end

  def start_week_cannot_include_period
    return unless regular_overlap(start_week).any?
    errors.add(:start_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
  end

  def start_week_cannot_overlap_period_wrap_around
    return unless finish_week > start_week && year_end_overlap(start_week).any?
    errors.add(:start_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
  end

  def finish_week_cannot_overlap_period_wrap_around
    return unless finish_week > start_week && year_end_overlap(finish_week).any?
    errors.add(:finish_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
  end

  def period_cannot_inbetween_and_other_period
    return unless period_overlap(start_week, finish_week).any?
    errors.add(:start_week, '-', :finish_week, 'cannot be in another Period')
  end

  def regular_overlap(week_of_year)
    self.class.where('start_week <= :week_of_year AND finish_week >= :week_of_year', week_of_year: week_of_year)
  end

  def year_end_overlap(week_of_year)
    self.class.where('finish_week < start_week AND (start_week <= :week_of_year OR finish_week >= :week_of_year)',
                     week_of_year: week_of_year)
  end

  def period_overlap(start_week, finish_week)
    self.class.where(':start_week <= start_week AND :finish_week >= finish_week', start_week, finish_week)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So period overlaps if original_start or original_end included in [start..end] or if [start..end] is included to [original_start ..original_end], for last case it is enough to check only one boundary.

```
scope :ovelapped_periods, ->(start, finish) { where(start_week: (start..finish)).or(end_week: (start..finish)).or(where(arel_table[:start_week].lt(start)).where(arel_table[:end_week].gt(start))) }
```

And I suggest leaving only one validation, to make the code more readable

```
validate :overlapping_period
def overlapping_period
  if self.class.ovelapped_periods(start_week, end_week).where.not(id: id).any?
    errors.add(:start_week, 'Period is overlapped other periods')
  end
end
```

Comment: I asked to question wrong, should be 
"period one is from 25-30 and if period two is created to be 20-40 it should error" 

instead of 
period one is from 20-40 and if period two is created to be 25-30 it should error

Comment: I also tried the first piece of code you suggested however it does work. I change it too 'end' to 'finish' however it has syntax error under the pipes in    |start, finish|

Comment: Sorry, forgot lambda syntax. It should be:
`scope :ovelapped_periods, ->(start, finish) { where(start_week: (start..finish)).or(end_week: (start..finish)).or(where(arel_table[:start_week].lt(start)).where(arel_table[:end_week].gt(start))) }
`
Changed an answer, it should work now